# Best way to get Github repository info using Service Account

Tags: github, github-api, service-accounts, github-api-v3, github-app

We're building a microservice to interact with Github REST API to **read** repository information within our organization. At the moment, we use individual user id and personal access token (created for the user id) to access the remote api programmatically.

Our requirement is to have a service account to access the api that has read privileges and no coupling with any individual. I was looking at Github Apps to perform the integration but it seem a bit complicated for our purpose as it focuses on making changes and handling events. We only need to read the repositories and collect information such as pull requests, commits etc. done on those repositories.

Are there any other simpler ways to achieve this?